# BigQuery abstraction of NULL concept to ALL

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd be interested to hear if there has been any discussion around the concept (it's an idea that came to me yesterday) of an ALL value, similar to NULL.

It'd be a special value that operates like this:

CAST(ALL AS STRING) = 'any_string' --> is always true
*value* IS ALL --> is true only for ALL values

I can see some good use cases - in where clauses where you'd want to include a set of records no matter what other set of records you are selecting by inclusion IN ('abc','cde'), the ALL's would come in.
But mainly in Looker Studio dashboards when you have more than one filter/dropdown control and non-overlapping metrics (stacked records) that you want to filter them independently.

Thanks!

Comment: CAST(ALL AS STRING) = 'any_string' --> is always true; value IS ALL --> is true only for ALL values

Comment: This is a feature request. You can submit these [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149). You wish for a special  marked entry that is not effected by filtering. However, this is not of any SQL standard. Instead you could define a value for yourself `ALWAYS`. `Select * from tbl WHERE (test in ('abc','cde') or test='ALWAYS')`. For Looker Studio this does not work. You could use a parameter for filtering or write your own custom vizualisation for the drop down filter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a feature request for BigQuery. We cannot solve or help here.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Appreciate the work-around idea, Samuel, I'll explore it! But just for the record, the post is not exactly a feature request, it's just about discussing the concept and learning whether something similar has been considered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.